# Possible reasons for SQS SendMessageBatch Failures

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Normally SQS `sendMessageBatchAsync` can fail due to many reasons (Over Message Size limits, service exception..), but I would like to know if the `sendMessageBatch` call is responded with 200 (OK), but there are failure entries in `sendMessageBatchResult`.

What are the possible reasons for this? I look at the AWS documentation but could not find much detail on this.

```
public Future<SendMessageBatchResult> sendMessageBatchAsync(String queueUrl, List<SendMessageBatchRequestEntry> entries)
```

Comment: It looks like the reason is supplied in [BatchResultErrorEntry](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_BatchResultErrorEntry.html). Admittedly, it doesn't list possible reasons, but at least it will return *a message explaining why the action failed on this entry.*

Comment: Yes, BatchResultErrorEntry provides the error code information, but i would like to know the possible error codes i can expect, so that my error handling code can handle them accordingly. I could n't find the documentation on possible error codes.

Comment: @nareshgoty did you find anything on this question ?